# A* Algorithm - Javascript: Why does my algorithm not find the shortest path

Tags: javascript, algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I am working on visualizing A*. I have a problem where the algorithm finds a path, but it is not the shortest. If I remove the part of the A* function code which is commented as 'tie-breaking', the algorithm finds the shortest path, but it searches the whole grid just like Dijkstra's algorithm, which I don't think A* is supposed to do. These are the pictures of the results with and without tie-breaking:

[With Tie-Breaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqKEu.png)
[Without Tie-Breaking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wDer.png)

What is wrong? Here is my A* function:

```
async a_star_search() {
    this.clearSearchNotWalls();
    let openSet = [];
    let closedSet = [];
    let start, end;
    let path = [];


    this.findNeighbors();


//shapes is a 2d array of squares... a grid
    for (let i = 0; i < this.shapes.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.shapes[0].length; j++) {
        if (this.shapes[i][j].type == "Start") {
          start = this.shapes[i][j];
        }
        if (this.shapes[i][j].type == "End") {
          end = this.shapes[i][j];
        }
      }
    }

    openSet.push(start);


    while (openSet.length > 0) {

      let lowestIndex = 0;
      //find lowest index
      for (let i = 0; i < openSet.length; i++) {
        if (openSet[i].F < openSet[lowestIndex].F)
          lowestIndex = i;

      }
      //current node
      let current = openSet[lowestIndex];

      //if reached the end
      if (openSet[lowestIndex] === end) {

        path = [];
        let temp = current;
        path.push(temp);
        while (temp.cameFrom) {
          path.push(temp.cameFrom);
          temp = temp.cameFrom;
        }
        console.log("Done!");
        for (let i = path.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          this.ctxGrid.fillStyle = "#ffff00";
          this.ctxGrid.fillRect(path[i].x, path[i].y, 14, 14);
          await new Promise(resolve =>
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
            }, this.animDelay / 2)
          );
        }
        break;
      }

      this.removeFromArray(openSet, current);
      closedSet.push(current);

      let my_neighbors = current.neighbors;
      for (let i = 0; i < my_neighbors.length; i++) {
        var neighbor = my_neighbors[i];

        if (!closedSet.includes(neighbor) && neighbor.type != "Wall") {
          let tempG = current.G + 1;

          let newPath = false;
          if (openSet.includes(neighbor)) {
            if (tempG < neighbor.G) {
              neighbor.G = tempG;
              newPath = true;
            }
          } else {
            neighbor.G = tempG;
            newPath = true;
            openSet.push(neighbor);
          }

          if (newPath) {
            neighbor.H = this.heuristic(neighbor, end);
            neighbor.G = neighbor.F + neighbor.H;
            neighbor.cameFrom = current;
          }

        }
      }


      //draw
      for (let i = 0; i < closedSet.length; i++) { //BLUE
        this.ctxGrid.fillStyle = "#4287f5";
        this.ctxGrid.fillRect(closedSet[i].x, closedSet[i].y, 14, 14);

      }
      for (let i = 0; i < openSet.length; i++) { //GREEN
        this.ctxGrid.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
        this.ctxGrid.fillRect(openSet[i].x, openSet[i].y, 14, 14);
      }
      await new Promise(resolve =>
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
        }, 10)
      );
    }
    if (openSet.length <= 0) {
      //no solution
    }

  }
```

Here is my heuristic function:

```
heuristic(a, b) {
    //let d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b.I - a.I, 2) + Math.pow(b.J - a.J, 2));
    let d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b.x - a.x, 2) + Math.pow(b.y - a.y, 2));
    return d;
  }
```

Comment: What are `.F` and `.G`? `.H` is the only one that is initialised properly in the code.

Comment: They are the F cost, G cost, and the H cost of the cells. I initialized them to 0 as default, but the algorithm still doesn't  work as it should even when i initialize them as something else.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include how you're initialising them?

Comment: I guess `neighbor.G = neighbor.F + neighbor.H;` should be `neighbor.F = neighbor.G + neighbor.H;`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was what was causing the error. Thanks for your help. I wish i can accept that answer if it wasn't a comment